# Publishing multiple variables using a single publisher

Tags: ros, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have written a publisher to publish a `float32` value to a topic `depth_m`. Now, I need to publish two more variables and they are of type `int`, not `float`. I would like all three of these variables to be published to the same topic. I am referring to the official [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber(c%2B%2B)). Do I just replace `Float32` in the following lines with `Int32` and add it to the existing publisher?

```
ros::Publisher depth_pub = pub_.advertise<std_msgs::Float32>("depth_m", 1000);
std_msgs::Float32 msg;
```

I believe I will have to edit `msg` to a different variable name `msg1`, `msg2`. According  to me the whole thing will have the following lines:

```
ros::Publisher depth_pub = pub_.advertise<std_msgs::Float32>("depth_m", 1000);
ros::Publisher depth_pub2 = pub_.advertise<std_msgs::Int32>("depth_m", 1000);

std_msgs::Float32 msg;
std_msgs::Int32 msg1;
std_msgs::Int32 msg2;    

msg.data=depth;
msg1.data=var1;
msg2.data=var2;

depth_pub.publish(msg); 
depth_pub2.publish(msg1);
depth_pub2.publish(msg2);
```

Is this the right strategy? If do this, will the whole thing act as a single message or multiple messages? Can I avoid two `advertise` lines by using just  `std_msgs` instead of `std_msgs::Float32`?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/244704/publishing-multiple-variables-using-a-single-publisher/) by [skr_robo](https://answers.ros.org/users/25555/skr_robo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 178 on 2016-09-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You cannot publish multiple different *types* of messages to the same topic. The ROS middleware does not support that. Each type will need its own topic.

You have two options:

1. if there is no correlation between your `Float32` and your `Int32` values (ie: they just happen to be published by the same program, but do not share any relationship), you could do what you are doing now: just create two separate publishers and use those.
2. if it makes sense for all three values to be published as a *single message*, you could create a new custom message containing three fields (two of type `int32`, one of type `float32`). Then create a publisher that publishes your custom message type instead of the `Int32` or `Float32` you have now. See the [Creating a ROS msg and srv](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingMsgAndSrv) tutorial for how to do that.

Note that I'd only recommend using option 2 if this makes sense for your data flows. *Don't* put things together just because it allows you to "avoid two `advertise` lines".

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-09-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [skr_robo](https://answers.ros.org/users/25555/skr_robo/) on 2016-09-28**:
Actually the three values are related and it would be helpful for them to stay together. I will try creating custom message type and will update soon. Thank You.

**Comment by [skr_robo](https://answers.ros.org/users/25555/skr_robo/) on 2016-09-28**:
It worked. Thank You.